# sprite not rotating correctly (cocos2d)

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, rotation, sprite

I have a turret on top of a tank base, both inside the same sprite sheet with frames correctly specified. When i build and run the project, I want the turret to rotate along the anchor point of the center of the tank. The turret is a child of the tank so that they will stay together when moving. However, when I try to rotate it, the turret seems to set its anchor point somewhere far off into the distance, like this:[image][image]

This is my init:

```
- (id)initWithLayer:(HelloWorldLayer *)layer type:(int)type hp:(int)hp {

NSString *spriteFrameName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tank%d_base.png", type];    
if ((self = [super initWithSpriteFrameName:spriteFrameName])) {
    _layer = layer;
    _type = type;
    self.hp = hp;
    _turret = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tank%d_turret.png", type]];
    _turret.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5, 0.25);
    [self scheduleUpdateWithPriority:-1];
    [self addChild:_turret];
     _turret.position = ccp(40, 50);
}

return self;
}
```

and I rotate the sprite here (I use a 360 degree shooting range)

```
- (void)shootToward:(CGPoint)targetPosition {

//CGPoint offset = ccpSub(targetPosition, self.position);
float x = abs(targetPosition.x) - self.position.x;
float y = abs(targetPosition.y) - self.position.y;
float angle;
float angleDegrees;
if (x < 0 && y > 0) {
    angle = atanf(y/x);
    angleDegrees = -CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angle) - 90;
}
else if (x < 0 && y < 0) {
    angle = atanf(y/x);
    angleDegrees = -CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angle) - 90;
}
else if (x > 0 && y < 0) {
    angle = atanf(y/x);
    angleDegrees = 90 - CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angle);
}
else if(x > 0 && y > 0) {
    angle = atanf(y/x);
    angleDegrees = 90 - CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angle);
}
switch (_layer.rotateInt) {
    case 0:
        angleDegrees = angleDegrees;
        break;
    case 1:
        angleDegrees = angleDegrees+ 180;
        break;
    case 2:
        angleDegrees = angleDegrees;
        break;
    case 3:
        angleDegrees = angleDegrees + 90;
        break;
    case 4:
        angleDegrees = angleDegrees - 90;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

NSLog(@"%f",angleDegrees);
_turret.rotation = angleDegrees;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. The only thing that I think could be causing this is that the turret asset is not centered or has a lot of blank space. That said, I'd try playing with the anchor point of the  turret.

Comment: The thing is, when I set it as a regular 'spriteWithFile:' it works, but it doesn't load up the correct image

Comment: I was thinking about it. How about setting the tank sprite anchor to self.anchor = ccp(0.5, 0.5)

Answer (score 0):

Since the turret is a child of the tank, this:

```
 _turret.position = ccp(40, 50);
```

offsets the turret by 40x50 away from the tank's origin (lower left corner of bounding box). Try settings the position so the turret is centered on the tank:

```
 _turret.position = ccp(tank.contentSize.width * tank.anchorPoint.x,
                        tank.contentSize.height * tank.anchorPoint.y);
```

Comment: that fixed it a little, but the problem is now that it's on the radius of a circle with the center at the tank.